# error in deploying a project using scrapyd

Tags: python, scrapy, scrapyd

I had multiple spiders in my project folder and want to run all the spiders at once, so i decided to run them using scrapyd service.
I have started doing this by seeing [here](http://scrapy.readthedocs.org/en/0.7/topics/scrapyd.html)

First of all i am in  current project folder

1. I had opened the `scrapy.cfg` file and uncommented the url line after

   [deploy]
2. I had run `scrapy server` command, that works fine and scrapyd server runs
3. I tried this command `scrapy deploy -l`

   Result :  `default              http://localhost:6800/`
4. when i tried this command `scrapy deploy -L scrapyd` i got following output

Result:

```
Usage
=====
  scrapy deploy [options] [ [target] | -l | -L <target> ]

deploy: error: Unknown target: scrapyd
```

when i tried to deploy the project with this command `scrapy deploy scrapyd -p default` got following error

```
Usage
=====
  scrapy deploy [options] [ [target] | -l | -L <target> ]

deploy: error: Unknown target: scrapyd
```

I am really unable to identify whey scrapyd is showing the above errors, can lead me in to a correct way of how to deploy a project in to scrapyd

Thanks in advance..........

**Edited Code**:

After seeing the answer of Peter Kirby,i named target in scrapy.cfg and tried the following command in my project folder,

**command**:

```
scrapy deploy ebsite -p ebsite
```

then i got the below error

```
Building egg of ebsite-1341808241
'build/lib' does not exist -- can't clean it
'build/bdist.linux-x86_64' does not exist -- can't clean it
'build/scripts-2.7' does not exist -- can't clean it
zip_safe flag not set; analyzing archive contents...
Deploying ebsite-1341808241 to http://localhost:6800/addversion.json
Deploy failed: <urlopen error [Errno 111] Connection refused>
```

How to solve this.....

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From scrapyd service documentation: (http://scrapy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/topics/scrapyd.html?highlight=scrapyd)

> You can define targets by adding them to your project’s scrapy.cfg
>   file... Here’s an example of defining a new target scrapyd2 with
>   restricted access through HTTP basic authentication:

```
[deploy:scrapyd2]
url = http://scrapyd.mydomain.com/api/scrapyd/
username = john
password = secret
```

Essentially what your error means is that your "target" name is not correct. If I remember correctly, the scrapy.cfg file sets the initial target name as "default". What you should be typing is something like:

```
scrapy deploy default -p project_name
```

Comment: Thanks for u r reply, as u said i edited my code as above and i got the error mentioned above,can u tell me how to solve that

Comment: Try accessing the Scrapyd web interface. Go to http://localhost:6800 or type curl http://localhost:6800/listprojects.json and tell me what happens. It might be that Scrapyd is installed incorrectly. What OS are you on?

Answer (score 1):

Just type `scrapy deploy` if you have no named targets and left settings at default!

Answer (score 1):

I got this error when I try to deploy my project without the scrapyd running, so simple run

```
scrapyd
```

on another terminal fixed the error

Answer (score 0):

This is the scrapyd proc have no permission!
You need kill the proc,then use root user,Just type:

```
scrapy server
```

then the new scrapyd will run.then you can do as [scrapyd documention](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/0.16/topics/scrapyd.html) says.